# API fetch console log doesn't print properly

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

When using fetch method for API, does anyone know why `.then(response => console.log(response.originator.name))` doesn't print any value?

`console.log(response)`

[image]

`console.log(response.content)` and `console.log(response.originator.name)`

[image]

I was trying to find answers for this but haven't had any luck so far. Any information would be appreciated.

```
function getQuote(){
 fetch('https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response.content))
    .then(response => console.log(response.originator.name))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));}
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/st3S1HM   <this image is when doing console.log(response.originator.name) only without having console.log(response.content)>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you put the second `console.log()` in a second `.then()`. This is receiving the result of the first `console.log()`, but `console.log()` doesn't return anything (and if it did return something, it would presumably be the object that it logged, not `response`). Put them both in the same `.then()`.

```
function getQuote() {  fetch('https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.content);
      console.log(response.originator.name);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```